# C++ __TIME__ is different when called from different files

Tags: c++, c, macros, preprocessor

I encountered this strange thing while playing around with predefined macros.
So basically, when calling `__TIME__` from different files, this happens:
[image: __TIME__ bug]

Is there anyway I can fix this? Or why does this happen?
All I am doing is `printf("%s\n", __Time__);` from different functions in different sources.

Comment: `__TIME__` expands to a string giving the time at which the current source file was compiled (or preprocessed).  So this is expected behavior because your source files were compiled 1 second apart.  What is it that you are really hoping to accomplish?

Comment: @NateEldredge I wanted to use __TIME__ as a random seed. I was doing this '#define __SHIFT_KEY (__TIME__[0] - '0' + __TIME__[1] - '0' + __TIME__[3] - '0' + __TIME__[4] - '0' + __TIME__[6] - '0' + __TIME__[7] - '0')' and needed __TIME__ to be the same in all of my sources. Is there anyway I can acomplish that ?

Comment: Please enclose code in backticks (`) marks so that it comes out formatted correctly.

Comment: So just to make sure, you want to use **compilation** time as a random seed?  This means that the resulting code will produce the same random numbers every time it is run, until you recompile.

Comment: @NateEldredge exactly

Comment: @NateEldredge Is there anyway to stick with the `__TIME__` macro? I need to use a macro for the seed

Comment: Side note: `__` is special character in Markdown, and it gets interpreted as __bold text__ You may want to put your snippets in backticks(\`\`) to avoid that.

Comment: @CataCata: Why must it be a macro?  It would be simpler to use `__TIME__` to initialize a global variable in one single file, and use that variable everywhere.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am trying to accomplish compile time string encryption using macros, and the only way to do that, is by using macros.

Comment: @CataCata: Okay, good luck then.  Too weird for me.

Comment: `gcc ... -DSEED=$(date +%s) ...` and use `SEED` instead of `__TIME__`

Comment: @pmg could you link me some more information about date and different formats/variables I can use ? This might be ideal for what I am doing.

Comment: I didn't know `+%s` by heart. I just typed `man date` to see the options. You can see the [POSIX `date` page online](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html)

Comment: @pmg I can't seem to get the date to display seconds only, btw im using VS2017. This is the format I have tried -DSEED=$(date +%S). Added it to CommandLine/Aditional Options.

Comment: It looks like POSIX does not have the `+%s` option or equivalent. You may want to use `+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` or `+%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.

Comment: @pmg I defined it as `-DSEED=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`  but when trying to print it `printf("%s :\n", SEED);` I get `'expected expression'` error.

Comment: Maybe VS2017 does not do [command substitutions like POSIX shells](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)?

Answer (score 4):

> Or why does this happen?

From the docs:

> This macro expands to a string constant that describes **the time at which the preprocessor is being run**.

If source files are compiled at different times, then the time will be different.

> Is there anyway I can fix this?

You could use a command line tool to generate the time string, and pass the string as a macro definition to the compiler. That way the time will be the same for all files compiled by that command.

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer

Comment: Is there any way I can store the `__TIME__` of a specific file as a macro ?

Comment: @CataCata sure, but that won't be useful for you, as you can only use the macro in the same translation unit where you define it.

Comment: @eerorika It might be useful.. How could I acomplish that ?

Comment: @CataCata simply define a macro: `#define SAME_TIME __TIME__`. Now, you can use `SAME_TIME` macro within that same translation unit, and it will produce the same result as `__TIME__`.

Comment: @eerorika This seems to not affect my issue at all somehow

Comment: @CataCata `#define SAME_TIME __TIME__` isn't expected to solve your problem.  It's a useless definition (hence "that won't be useful for you") since it's only good within the same translation unit (i.e. source file) and therefore is completely equivalent to just using `__TIME__` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question: `__TIME__` is going to be different for different files because it specifies the time when that specific file was compiled.

However, you're asking [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  To address what you're actually trying to do:

If you need a compilation-time value, you're better off letting your *build* system specify it.  That is, with `make` or whatever you're using, generate a random seed somehow, then pass that to the compiler as a command-line option to define your *own* preprocessor macro (e.g. `gcc -DMY_SEED=$(random_value) ...`).  Then you could apply that to *all* C files that you compile and have each of them use `MY_SEED` however you want.

Comment: That's basically the same as eerorika's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your use case is kind of weird, but a simple way to get the same time in all files is to use `__TIME__` in exactly one source file, and use it to initialize a global variable:

compilation_time.h:

```
const char *compilation_time;
```

compilation_time.c:

```
#include "compilation_time.h"
const char *compilation_time = __TIME__;
```

more_code.c:

```
#include "compilation_time.h"
...
    printf("%s\n", compilation_time);
```

If you really want to construct an integer as in your comment (which may be non-portable as it assumes ASCII), you could do

seed.h:

```
const int seed;
```

seed.c:

```
#include "seed.h"
const int seed = (__TIME__[0] - '0') + ...;
```

more_code.c:

```
#include "compilation_time.h"
...
    srand(seed);
```